# How does salvagewallet work?

Tags: wallet.dat, lost-wallet

What can I expect using the `salvagewallet` command?
What is it actually doing?

I am asking specifically about the zcoin fork, if that matters.
How can this help with corrupted wallet?
How can Wallets become corrupted in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

zcoin seems to be a fork of Bitcoin Core.

Bitcoin Core's `-salvagewallet` does carefully try to recover a broken wallet database (wallet.dat file).

What it does is:

1. Copy the wallet.dat file (`wallet.<date>.bak`)
2. Tries to recover only the private keys

Make sure you check your `debug.log` after `-salvagewallet` wallet operation.
Look for lines starting with "`Salvage`" to get more information.